# Fixed element's width

Tags: css, css-position, fixed-width

I have a timer bar showing the remaining time of a contest. As the user answers more questions of the event, scrolling down, I want the timer to be fixed in its position. I know this can be achieved by setting the CSS `position` to `fixed`.

But `fixed` needs either a `width` set for the element, or `left` and `right` values. My problem is that the layout of the page is boxed, with margins at the left and right of the "box", and it depends on the user's viewport, how much width there is for the box in the middle...

How can I calculate the width once the page loads and then set that width to the timer bar in order for `fixed` property to get the data it needs?

I tried setting it to 100%, but for `position: fixed` 100% means 100% of the viewport, not of the parent element, so the bar grows from the right, outside of the viewport (if you can get what I mean), since there are margins on the left and right of the boxed layout...

Comment: Could you share some representative HTML?

Comment: It's very complex, so complex that I can't easily construct a minimal reproducible example... I'll try my best to do that, but I doubt I'll be able to achieve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: sticky;`

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 768px;
}

.progress {
  position: sticky;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}

/* tall content to cause scrollbars */
main > div {
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title above stickied progress</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="progress">
        <progress></progress>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div>Example of a very long step</div>
        <div>Example of a very long step</div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: For some strange reason when I tried `position: sticky` it didn't work for me. Now it works like a charm... I don't know what to say. Thanks a million! :D

Comment: I think I hadn't set the top property, and because the website has a sticky header as well, my progress bar was hiding behind the sticky header... Now that I saw you setting the `top`, I changed it to 150px, and indeed it worked like a charm! Probably that's what I had missed when I tried it alone!

Comment: Yay! And yes - you need to tell `sticky` where the thing should go! As MDN puts it: a "stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed." That threshold comes from the positional value(top/bottom/etc). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning

Comment: "You must specify a threshold with at least one of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` for sticky positioning to behave as expected. Otherwise, it will be indistinguishable from relative positioning."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'vw' CSS unit to get a percentage of viewport width. For example `width: 50vw;` would set it to 50% of the current viewport width.

You can also use `calc()` to do calculations. For example, if I know I want something to be a third of the current viewport width I could set `width: calc(100vw/3);`